# coding a pygame level editor

Tags: python, pygame

Hi guys i need help creating a level editor that dumps all the information on a .txt file
this is how i wil read the data:

```
def load_map(path):
    f = open(path + '.txt','r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    data = data.split('\n')
    game_map = []
    for row in data:
        game_map.append(list(row))
    return game_map
```

```
for layer in game_map:
        x = 0
        for tile in layer:
            if tile == '1':
                display.blit(dirt_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
                minimap.blit(dirt_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
            if tile == '2':
                display.blit(grass_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
                minimap.blit(grass_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
            if tile == '3':
                display.blit(grass_right_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
                minimap.blit(grass_right_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
            if tile == '4':
                display.blit(grass_left_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
                minimap.blit(grass_left_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
            if tile == '5':
                display.blit(dirt_right_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
                minimap.blit(dirt_right_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
            if tile == '6':
                display.blit(dirt_left_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
                minimap.blit(dirt_left_img,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))

            
            if tile == '7':
                display.blit(abyss,(x*16-scroll[0],y*16-scroll[1]))
            
            if tile != '0':
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x*16,y*16,16,16))
            x += 1
        y += 1
```

If its not to much of a trouble could you please send some code over for me to try. This is in pygame and i just started! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Dump the map information into a text file

```py
def dump_map(path, map_data):
    with open(path + '.txt', 'w') as file:
        for row in map_data:
            file.write(''.join(row) + '\n')
```

Comment: thanks bro ima check it whne i get home